# please somebody tell me the origin of the words, prosecutor

Tags: prosecutorial-discretion

Please somebody tell me the origin of the words, prosecutor, prosecution and other relevant similar words please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about etymology, not law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It derives from Latin [prosequor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prosequor#Latin) "to follow, pursue" (via the [past participle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prosecute), whence the *t*).